# SQL. Разделить ИИФ, ИФФ и ИФ на три столбца

Tags: sql

Нужен запрос, который отделит имена от фамилий и  разделит данные на Имя(включая второе) и Фамилию. Вот примеры исходных строк:

```
--Самуэль Л. Джексон
--Сильвестер Сталлоне
--Томми Ли Джонс
--Катерина Зета-Джонс
```

Пока написала это, но не могу придумать как создать ещё одну колонку (secondname), чтобы потом объединить имена в одну ячейку (имя)

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(xxx, ' ', 1) AS firstname,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(xxx, ' ', - 1) AS surname
    FROM Tab
```

Comment: Выделение группы номер `@N` выполняется двойным применением функции: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, @delimiter, @N), @delimiter, -1)`. Но надо учитывать, что "подстрок" может быть меньше, чем @N, и тогда несколько последних получатся идентичными.

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно именно без идентичных. Там где нет второго имени нужно получить NULL

Comment: НУ посчитаешь, сколько пробелов в значении, а потом CASE в руки..

Comment: Akina, пожалуйста, напишите как это сделать  реально спасёте, я не усну, пока не увижу решение

Comment: А по какому принципу вы собираетесь определить что в строке "Хелена Бонем Картер" нужно в первое имя записать "Хелена", во второе NULL, а в фамилию "Бонем Картер"?

Comment: За основу беру, что последнее слово в строке, это точно фамилия. Зета-Джонс считать одним словом